# How to properly use the map and map! methods

Tags: ruby

I am working on a caesar cipher which is a real simple cipher which shifts each letter in a message to the right in accordance with a given key. For example, with a key of 3, the message "hello" would become encrypted as "ifmmp"

I have written this program as a series of loops which are... I forgot the term, but its where you have a loop inside of a loop. The term escapes me at the moment.

Anyway, the way I am doing this is by first converting the message, which might consist of several statements, into an array of words.

Then, I am converting each of those words into an array of letters, so that I can shift them individually.

Finally, I am merging the array of letters into a single words, and I am merging the array of words back into a single message.

The problem I am running into is that whenever I am trying to use the map and map! methods, I cannot get the shifted letters to retain their value. I come from a C/C++ background, and in those languages I wouldn't have a problem with doing this because I understand how pointers and references work, but I don't know how this works in Ruby.

My question is: How can I get the values of an array to be changed inside of a loop, and not reset back to their original values once I exit the loop? The commented code is as follows:

```
 def caesar_cipher(message,key)
    #Convert message to array
    message = message.split(' ')
    #Map each word in the array to the cipher method
    message.map! do |word|
        puts "message is: #{message} and the current word is: #{word}"
        #Split each word into an array of characters
        word = word.split('')           
        puts "after splitting word is: #{word.inspect}"
        #Map each letter to cipher function
        word.map do |letter|                
            puts "trying to shift the letter: #{letter.inspect}"
            #Based on the value of the key, each letter will be shifted to the right key times
            key.times do                    
                #Cases when the letter is at the end of the alphabet
                case letter
                when "z"
                    letter = "a"
                when "Z"
                    letter = "A"
                #By default, each letter will be shifted to the next letter in the alphabet per each iteration of the loop
                else 
                    letter = letter.next!
                end
                puts "the letter is now: #{letter.inspect}"
            end
            #Join the array of letters back into a single word
            word = word.join('')
            puts "after joining word is: #{word.inspect}"
        end
    end
    #Join the array of words back into the shifted message
    message.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: I've updated your indentation to reflect the actual code... have a look at what's *inside* a loop that it shouldn't be

Comment: Also - when trying to figure out what's going wrong, it's often good to use `puts` to print out the current message/word/letter in each iteration of a loop to see what you get for each loop... it will often make very clear what's wrong. I'll add some puts statements to your code and you should have a go at running it with them in, and seeing what the output is

Comment: That's not how ruby comments work :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I added those comments just before posting the code, and I forgot that Ruby comments are with a #. Editing to fix

Comment: Shouldn't the key referenced in your first paragraph be `1`? The technical term for what you describe in the following paragraph is *loop de loop*, derived from the French, *boucle de la boucle*.

Comment: More commonly known as a nested loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was mostly fine. I made just two tiny fixes

```
def caesar_cipher(message,key)
    message = message.split(' ')
    message.map! do |word|      
        word = word.split('')           
        word.map! do |letter| # or word = word.map                
            key.times do                    
                case letter
                when "z"
                    letter = "a"
                when "Z"
                    letter = "A"
                else 
                    letter = letter.next!
                end
            end
            letter # return the next letter from the block
        end
        word.join('')
    end
    message.join(' ')
end               

puts caesar_cipher('hello', 2)
# >> jgnnq
```

#### What you were doing wrong

- The values were not retaining changes because you didn't save them (`map` doesn't change the original array, it returns a changed copy)
- Sometimes, return value of `word.map` was `letter.next!` (because it was the last expression evaluated in the block), which is a number, not a letter. You need to always return the letter.

Comment: Awesome! This is it... Thanks! 

Do you think you can explain what I was doing wrong?

I know you commented in the changes, but I am not exactly sure what was going wrong with what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the question, but you might find a more functional approach useful.

I try to reduce nested loops and conditional branch logic where possible, as they can be quite painful to follow.

```
def caesar_cipher(message, key)
  key.times do 
    message = message
      .split("")   
      .map(&:ord)  # convert each character to ascii number
      .map(&:next) # increment ascii number by 1
      .map(&:chr)  # convert ascii number back to character
      .join        
      .gsub("{", "a") # fix characters out of range
      .gsub("[", "A")
  end
  message
end
```

Comment: replace `.map{ |digit| digit += 1 } ` with `.map(&:next)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Ah, nice one.